# Android Studio Gradle sync says not able to download gradle-3.1.3.pom

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Almost wasted my day resolving below error. Could not get any leads.

```
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'. Received status code 500 from server: Internal Server Error
```

I am using distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties

Manually i can download this file on same network, but in Andriod Studio i get above error and sync fails.

My top-level build file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {       
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

Any help apprieciated

Comment: try this classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0"

Comment: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'. Received status code 500 from server: Internal Server Error
Same error...

Comment: if you are using the android studio less than version 3, then you need to add this line inside the repository tag maven {   url "https://maven.google.com"   } and remove google()

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.1.4. Still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open "gradle.properties" and then remove proxy settings lines from it. Build Project again.